# Nested for-loops: is this doing what I think it is?

Tags: r

So I have a dataset (data), that contains 322 observations of 6 variables. I'm regressing an outcome called "water" on "reserved". (For anyone curious, it's about whether female politicians in India choose water treatment policies more often than male politicians.)

My intention is to run 1000 regressions, each one with a random-sized sample of the 322 observations, and store those 1000 coefficients in a vector (coefs). Next, I'd like to repeat the previous calculation 10 times -- each time taking the mean of coefs and placing it in a vector (temp_mean).

Does my code below actually accomplish this? Does it matter whether I put temp_mean[j] inside the 2nd to last bracket or outside it? (When I run it, the results are the same either way.)

This appears to be functioning how I want it to, but I wanted to get some other input. And by the way, I know there are faster ways to do this with other packages and with apply, but I wanted to practice the concept of a nested for-loop.

```
coefs <- vector()
temp_mean <- vector()
for (j in 1:10){
  for (i in 1:1000){
    df <- data[sample(nrow(data), sample(nrow(data), 1)),]
    my_reg <- lm(water ~ reserved, data=df)
    coefs[i] <- my_reg[[1]][2]
  }
  temp_mean[j] <- mean(coefs, na.rm=T)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the inner-loop, it seems to me that each iteration a random number of rows is selected by using sample(nrow(data), 1). This means that your regression data set could be as small as one if sample(nrow(data), 1) = 1 and your regression would not be so accurate. If you intend to select 322 observations randomly each time I suggest using

```
df <- data[sample(nrow(data), 322, replace = FALSE),]
```